# Concatenation of vectors

Tags: c++, vector

My apologies for the title, I did not know of a better one.

So, basically, I have a 1D vector, which I extract 256 pieces of data from this, until there is no more data left.

```
std::size_t begin = 0;
std::size_t nextEnd = 0;        

while (nextEnd < signal.size()) {
  begin = nextEnd;
  nextEnd += 256; 
  Transform(signal, begin, std::min(nextEnd, signal.size()));
}
```

Inside the "Transform" function, there is a new, temp vector created called `temp_vector` and inside my main I have a global 1D vector.

What I want to do is, every iteration of this loop, the values of the `temp_vector` is pushed back into the `global 1D vector` at the right position.

So for example:

```
std::vector<double> global; 
std::vector<double> actual = {1,1,0,0,2, 3, 4 ....., n};  

// here loop over n number of elements 

// TRANSFORM:
   // std::vector<double> temp_vector = {10, 50}; // after calculations 
   // global.push_back(temp_vector);
```

So at the end result, the `global_vector` will still be a 1D vector, however, will contain all of the values, in the same place for each of the elements.

I hope I have explained myself enough!

Comment: @user1326876 - this is up for a close vote. I think its a quality question, but its not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Could you provide examples? For example, show what you start with in `actual` with a small data set, describe the transform, and then show what `global` looks like at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code for array merging:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
        std::vector<int> glob = {1, 2, 3};
        std::vector<int> temp_vector = {4, 5, 6};

        glob.insert(glob.end(), temp_vector.begin(), temp_vector.end());

        std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = glob.begin();
        for(; it != glob.end(); ++it) {
                std::cout << *it << ", ";
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
./a.out
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
```

Comment: But, what if you don't know the size of `glob` vector?

Comment: It doesn't matter. new values will be added at the end and glob vector size will be expanded accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use an ordered container like `std::set` or `std::priority_queue` and insert into that container directly, not using a temporary.